# Comment box using jquery, ajax and asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I am working with ASP.Net web application. I need comment control such as [this](https://pinterest.com/) or [this](http://www.trippy.com/)

when we register on above site it's allow as to comment on deals.

Here I am able to make template like above site now I am facing problem  with commenter option. If you have any idea please share

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Facebook Comments Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/), it is very good & very easy to integrate.

[image]

**Facebook Comments Plugin**

Comments Box is a social plugin that enables user commenting on your site. Features include moderation tools and distribution.

Social Relevance: Comments Box uses social signals to surface the highest quality comments for each user. Comments are ordered to show users the most relevant comments from friends, friends of friends, and the most liked or active discussion threads, while comments marked as spam are hidden from view.

Distribution: Comments are easily shared with friends or with people who like your Page on Facebook. If a user leaves the “Post to Facebook” box checked when she posts a comment, a story appears on her friends’ News Feed indicating that she’s made a comment on your website, which will also link back to your site.

Answer (score -2):

Check out: [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

They've got [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and there are plugins for [watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/).

PS: You probably want to list the features you'd like in your control instead of letting people figure out for you which functionality the textboxes on trippy.com have to offer...